# Binding without DependencyProperty

Tags: data-binding, dependency-properties

How to bind property in Two Way?

Here is my Code:

```
    public interface IDataOperations
{
    string GetData();
    string SaveData();
}//close interface

public class Vendor : IDataOperations
{
    private string _vendorName = "My Vendor Name";

    public string VendorName
    {
        get { return _vendorName; }
        set { _vendorName = value; }
    }
}
```

How can I bind VendorName in my Xaml? I need to bind to Text Box in such a way that if user changes text box value, it should also change the value of that VendorObject too.

Where should I declare VendorObject? Either in xaml.cs file or xaml by using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your XAML code should look like
`<TextBox Binding="{VendorName}" Name="textBox1" />`
and on your Window_Loaded function add this code:
`textBox1.DataContext=v;`
where v is an instance of the Vendor class.

Comment: Got that..i was able to do this like:
<TextBox x:Name="txtVendorName" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=VendorObject}"  Width="200" Height="50" BorderBrush="Black" Text="{Binding Path=VendorName}" />

Comment: and off course _this is my current window name. i.e., x:Name="_this"
Just for the record.